# regex for floating point number less than or equal to 4.5

Tags: regex

I am trying `^[0-4][\.][0-5][0-9]*` but it is also working for numbers like `4.56` and it doesn't match numbers like `3.958`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215089/regex-for-floating-point-number-less-than or equal to-4-5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this pattern:

```
^(?:[0-3](?:\.[0-9]+)?|4(?:\.[0-4][0-9]*)?|4\.50*|-[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$
    ^^^                 ^^^                ^^^   ^^^
    0 to 3              4.0...4.4999...    4.5   any negative number
```

This says to match `0` through `3`, followed by any optional decimal component, or `4` followed by `0` through `4`, then any other number.  The last portion of the alternation allows for any negative number.

### Demo

But, that being said, the far easier way to do this comparison would be to use an inequality operator in your programming language.  For example, the complex regex above can be replaced in Java using:

```
float f = 3.4f;
if (f <= 4.5f) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

Comment: @Muhammadvakili Added a fix for that.  Though the OP makes no mention that the input could be negative.

Comment: Less than 4.5 includes negative numbers... The OP doesn't mention it couldn't be negative either. Either way it's a great answer.

Comment: thank you but it is not working for 4.5 sorry for not mentioning in question

Comment: @DilmurodIsmoilov I have updated the pattern to also allow `4.5` exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
^(?!.*4\.([5]+[0]*[1-9]+|[6-9][0-9]*))([0-4](?:\.[0-9]*)?)$|(\-[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VJRRKk/8)